# Realm: How to query with many to many field

Tags: android, realm

I recently heard about Realm for android (also available for iOS) in this talk by [Joaquim Verques](http://realm.io/news/joaquim-verges-making-falcon-pro-3/) . Very interesting and very powerful tool for persistent data.

I decided to give it a try after the video, researching and reading the documentation.

I found it very easy to use and set up but i end up stuck in the middle of my project because i couldn't manage to successfully make a query with many to many relationships.

I have created a small example for this topic.

My models:

```
public class Feed extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String link;
    private Terms terms;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Terms getTerms() {
        return terms;
    }

    public void setTerms(Terms terms) {
        this.terms = terms;
    }
}

    public class Terms extends RealmObject {

        private String tag;
        private RealmList<Category> categories;

        public String getTag() {
            return tag;
        }

        public void setTag(String tag) {
            this.tag = tag;
        }

        public RealmList<Category> getCategories() {
            return categories;
        }

        public void setCategories(RealmList<Category> categories) {
            this.categories = categories;
        }
    }

    public class Category extends RealmObject {
        @PrimaryKey
        private int id;
        private String name;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

So far so good, now im going to save a list of feeds to realm (make it persistent) and then try to make some query.

```
    public static void test(final Context context,final List<Feed> feedList) {
          Realm realm = null;
                        try {
                        realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(feedList);
                        realm.commitTransaction();
RealmResults<Feed> realmResults = realm.where(Feed.class).findAll();// return me all feeds
                    RealmResults<Feed> realmResults1 = realm.where(Feed.class).equalTo("id", 1).findAll(); // return feed with id 1
                    RealmResults<Feed> realmResults2 = realm.where(Feed.class).equalTo("terms.tag", "tech").findAll(); // return  feeds //with tag = "tech"
                    RealmResults<Feed> realmResults3 = realm.where(Feed.class).equalTo("terms.category.name", "test").findAll(); //exception here
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            //Empty
                            Log.d("Test","",e);
                        } finally {
                            if (realm != null)
                                realm.close();
                        }
                    }
    }
```

Everything run well untill the last query and i get this exception:"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query: category does not refer to a class."

So my question is How do i do that kind of query successfully, as i will like realm to return me every feed with terms which has at least 1 category with name = "test"

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your field is called "categories" and not "category". The third query should be:

```
RealmResults<Feed> realmResults3 = realm.where(Feed.class).equalTo("terms.categories.name", "test").findAll();
```

Comment: Hi thank you, i cannot believe i have missed that one. But unfortunately in my example it return me an empty realmResult and yes i have the objects im looking for in the "database". :(

Comment: Is it only `realmResults3` which is empty?

Comment: it is all good now it was my bad as i was looking for something that does not exist! Thank you for your time and im quit excited to use Realm in my future  as it is so cool and fast! (y)

Comment: Hi, @geisshirt, i am facing the same problem although i am not querying against wrong field, Can you please tell me what might be wrong? I am using version `0.87.0`

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal Can you share your classes and query? Otherwise it is a bit hard to tell what is wrong.